# DSolve will not apply assumption m ∈ Integers

Tags: differential-equations, assumptions, trigonometry

I am trying to solve a linear second order ODE using `DSolve` which involves an arbitrary integer `m`. `DSolve` gives me a solution when I set `m` to a particular integer (I have tried several, including negative/positive, even/odd, and `0`).  When I try to use the assumption `m ∈ Integers` and ask `DSolve` to solve this ODE for an arbitrary integer `m`, it does not work. 
Here is the input:

```
$Assumptions = m ∈ Integers
testk = 
  0 == -16 c m^2 Cos[x] k[x] - c (-7 Sin[x] + Sin[3x]) k'[x] 
       + Cos[x] Sin[x]^2 (m^2 (3 + 4 m Cos[x] + Cos[2 x]) Tan[x/2]^(2 m) + 4 c k''[x])

DSolve[ testk, k[x], x]
```

> ```
> DSolve[ 0 == -16 c m^2 Cos[x] k[x] - c (-7 Sin[x] + Sin[3 x]) k'[x] 
>               + Cos[x] Sin[x]^2 (m^2 (3 + 4 m Cos[x] + Cos[2 x]) Tan[x/2]^(2 m)
>               + 4 c k''[x], k[x], x]
> ```

Update:
I have realized that the problem is that `DSolve` does not apply any of the global assumptions. Does anyone know how I can make `DSolve` apply the assumption that `m ∈ Integers`? I have tried using `Assuming[,]` to set the assumptions locally but that did not work either.

Comment: I do not think DSolve uses/accepts user assumptions. This was my understanding all along. Unless something changed in newer version of M.

Comment: @Nasser Functions called by `DSolve` use `$Assumptions` (`Simplify`, `Refine`, `Integrate` etc.), but otherwise I don't think `DSolve` uses it.  I think `DSolve` gets stuck trying to figure out how to reduce the problem to integrals.

Answer (score 2):

I think I have solved this ODE (I didn't verify the solution). The problem with `DSolve` is `Integrate` was not terminating for this inhomogeneous equation.

So what I did was solve the homogeneous equation, then applied variation of parameters described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_of_parameters#General_second_order_equation):

```
homode = -16c*m^2Cos[x]k[x] - c(Sin[3x] - 7Sin[x])k'[x] + 4c*Cos[x]Sin[x]^2k''[x] == 0;

homsol = First[k[x] /. DSolve[homode, k[x], x]];

u1 = homsol /. {C[1] -> 1, C[2] -> 0};
u2 = homsol /. {C[1] -> 0, C[2] -> 1};

f = m^2(3 + 4m Cos[x] + Cos[2x])Tan[x/2]^(2m)Cos[x]Sin[x]^2/(4c*Cos[x] Sin[x]^2);

W = Wronskian[homode, k, x];

A = -HoldForm[Integrate[#, x]]&[u2*f/W];
B = HoldForm[Integrate[#, x]]&[u1*f/W];

TraditionalForm[k[x] == u1 C[1] + u2 C[2] + A u1 + B u2]
```

[image]

## --- Edit ---

I have verified this solution is correct and I thought I'd share because this is the first time I've found a real use for `Inactive` over `Hold`... exciting!

So instead of using `HoldForm` to hold `A` and `B`, I use `Inactivate`:

```
A = Inactivate[-Integrate[u2*f/W, x], Integrate];
B = Inactivate[Integrate[u1*f/W, x], Integrate];

final = u1 C[1] + u2 C[2] + A u1 + B u2;

FullSimplify[testk /. {k[x] -> final, k'[x] -> D[final, x], k''[x] -> D[final, {x, 2}]}]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Comment: By substitution, I have verified that this solution by @Chip Hurst is formally correct, although I believe that t should be replaced by x in the definitions of A and B.

Comment: @bbgodfrey yes, thank you! This is fixed now.

Comment: very nice use of `Inactivate`, which I had not seen before.  Allows a much simpler method to verify correctness of solution than the method I used.  By the way, assuming m>0 and running `Simplify` on the solution gives a somewhat simpler answer.

Answer (score 2):

**Update:** I thought I would check this out in V10.1. I found no difference in `DSolve`, but I was able to an answer relatively quickly (compare with my original attempt).  It's in a different form than the original, but it's equivalent.

Using the same substitution as [Chip Hurst](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/4346/chip-hurst) in his Apr 22 answer, and after some coaxing, I got to this solution:

```
testk = 0 == -16 c m^2 Cos[x] k[x] - c (-7 Sin[x] + Sin[3 x]) k'[x] + 
    Cos[x] Sin[x]^2 (m^2 (3 + 4 m Cos[x] + Cos[2 x]) Tan[x/2]^(2 m) + 
       4 c k''[x]);
ode = testk /. x -> x[u] /. 
       First@Solve[{h'[u] == D[k[x[u]], u], 
          h''[u] == D[k[x[u]], u, u]}, {k'[x[u]], k''[x[u]]}] /. 
      k[x[u]] -> h[u] /. x -> ArcCos /. 
    Tan[ArcCos[u]/2]^a_ :> ((1 - u)/(1 + u))^(a/2) // FullSimplify;

solu = DSolve[ode, h, u];

Assuming[m ∈ Integers && m >= 0,
  fubar = Simplify[h[Cos[x]] /. First@solu] /. 
     Exp[A__*ArcTanh[Cos[x]]] :>
       Simplify[ExpToTrig[Simplify[TrigToExp[E^(A ArcTanh[Cos[x]])]]]] // 
    Simplify
  ];

solx = Function @@ {x, fubar}
(*
  Function[x, (1/(8 c m (-1 + 4 m^2))) * 
   (m^3 (-((-1 + Cos[x])^2/(1 + Cos[x])))^m *
      (1 + 4 m^2 + 4 m Cos[x] + (-1 + 4 m^2) Cos[2 x]) + 
    4 c (-1 + Cos[x])^m * 
      ((-1 + 4 m^2) C[1] - m C[2] + 2 m ((-1 + 4 m^2) C[1] + m C[2]) Cos[x]) * 
      Cosh[m (Log[1 + Cos[x]] - Log[2 Sin[x/2]^2])] - 
    4 c (-1 + Cos[x])^m * 
      ((-1 + 4 m^2) * C[1] + m C[2] + 2 m ((-1 + 4 m^2) C[1] - m C[2]) Cos[x]) * 
      Sinh[m (Log[1 + Cos[x]] - Log[2 Sin[x/2]^2])])]
*)
```

Check:

```
Assuming[m ∈ Integers,
 testk /. k -> solx // FullSimplify
 ]
(*  True  *)
```

---

**Original solution found**

For what it's worth, using the same substitution as [Chip Hurst](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/4346/chip-hurst) in his Apr 22 answer, and after some coaxing, I originally got to this solution:

```
solx = Function[x, 
  1/(4 Sqrt[
    m^2]) (2 C[1] (1 + 2 Sqrt[m^2] Cos[x]) Cot[x/2]^(-2 Sqrt[m^2]) - (
     2 C[2] (Sqrt[m^2] - 2 m^2 Cos[x]) Cot[x/2]^(2 Sqrt[m^2]))/(-1 + 
      4 m^2) + ((m^2)^(
      3/2) (1 + 2 m Cos[x] + (-1 + 4 m^2) Cos[x]^2) Tan[x/2]^(2 m))/(
     c (-1 + 4 m^2)))]
```

Unfortunately, crashes, trying different things, memory leaks or something messing up `Simplify` and `FullSimplify` or other confusing behavior, plus stupidly copying and saving the wrong step means there is one step missing in the path to the solution.

Check:

```
testk /. k -> solx // Simplify
(*  True  *)
```

[It is arguably a simpler solution, but I did not discover a way to transform the new solution to this one.]

One of the problems is that applying the assumption that `m` is an integer causes different things to happen under the hood in simplification.  But some simplifications are valid whether `m` is an integer or not.  The following example shows that an early application of the assumption slows things down quite a bit.  Simplifications are usually done under time constraints, which may lead to failure.

```
ode /. First@solu // 
  Simplify[#, m ∈ Integers && u ∈ Reals] & // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {17.843582, True} *)

ode /. First@solu // Simplify // 
  Simplify[#, m ∈ Integers && u ∈ Reals] & // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {7.273103, True}  *)
```

It is a sheer guess that this has something to do with the problem.

Comment: Very nice! I have no idea why my ODE didn't solve with `DSolve` since it works for me in V9 and V10 today.

Comment: @ChipHurst  If you throw in the assumption `Element[m, Integers]` with `DSolve` (with `Assuming`, say), `DSolve` runs longer than I'm willing to wait.  That may be the difference between now and before.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will help, but you can transform your ODE to have rational coefficients by subbing $t = \cos x$, which gives

$k'(x)=-\sqrt{1-t^2} k'(t), \quad k''(x)=(1-t^2)k''(t)-t k'(t), \;\; \text{ and } \;\; x=\cos ^{-1}(t)$:

```
testk=-16 c m^2 Cos[x] k[x]-c (-7 Sin[x]+Sin[3x]) k'[x]+Cos[x] Sin[x]^2 (m^2 (3+4 m Cos[x]+Cos[2 x]) Tan[x/2]^(2 m)+4 c k''[x]);

$fromTrig={k'[x]:>(-Sqrt[1-t^2])*k'[t],k[x]->k[t],k''[x]->-t*k'[t]+k''[t]-t^2*k''[t],x->ArcCos[t]};

simped = Simplify[FunctionExpand[testk/.$fromTrig],-1<t<1&&m\[Element]Integers];

Collect[(1+t)^m PowerExpand[simped], {k[t],k'[t],k''[t]}]==0
```

> ```
> -2 m^2 (1-t)^m t (-1+t^2) (1+2 m t+t^2)-16 c m^2 t (1+t)^m k[t] + 
>   8 c (1+t)^m (-1+t^2) k'[t]+4 c t (1+t)^m (-1+t^2)^2 k''[t] == 0
> ```

Comment: You might be interested in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

*Update for V13.1*

I thought @Steven_Huang was using V13, but apparently not or not interested in posting this V13 solution.  Now `DSolve[testk, k[x], x]` returns a somewhat long answer without assumptions.  Here's what `DSolve[]` gives now with assumptions and simplifying:

```
testk = 0 == -16 c m^2 Cos[x] k[x] - c (-7 Sin[x] + Sin[3 x]) k'[x] + 
    Cos[x] Sin[x]^2 (m^2 (3 + 4 m Cos[x] + Cos[2 x]) Tan[x/2]^(2 m) + 
       4 c k''[x]);

Assuming[
 m ∈ Integers && m > 0 && -Pi < x < Pi,
 sol = DSolve[testk, k[x], x] // FullSimplify
 ]
(*
{{k[x] -> (E^(I x) (-1 + E^(I x))^(-4 m) (4 (64^
            m m^2 (1 + m Cos[x]) (-1 + 
              2 m Cos[x]) ((I + Cot[x]) Sin[x/2]^4)^(2 m) Sin[x]^2 + 
           4 c Cos[x] ((1 + E^(I x))^(4 m) m C[2] (-1 + 2 m Cos[x]) + 
              2 (-1 + E^(I x))^(4 m) (-1 + 4 m^2) C[1] *
               (1 + 2 m Cos[x])) (I Tan[x/2])^(2 m)) +
         (-1 + E^(I x))^(4 m) m^2 (1 + 2 m Cos[x]) (2 + 8 m^2 + 
           2 (-1 + 4 m^2 + m Cos[x]) Cos[2 x]) Tan[x/2]^(2 m))) /
            (16 c (1 + E^(2 I x)) m (-1 + 4 m^2))}}
*)
```

Since the ODE and the generic solution returned by `DSolve[testk, k[x], x]` are both periodic of period `2 Pi`, restricting the domain to `-Pi < x < Pi` yields a general solution valid over its domain by periodicity.