# NDSolve and assuming

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to solve the system of PDE with NDSolve and I got an error message like this

> NDSolve::deqn: "Equation or list of equations expected instead of
>
> ConditionalExpression[[Eta]r[[Xi]r]==Ir[[Xi]r] (26/125
>   (1+Times[<<2>>])+2 Re[Times[<<2>>]])+Il[[Xi]l]
>   (Im[Times[<<2>>]+Times[<<4>>]+Times[<<2>>]]-13/125
>   Re[Times[<<2>>]])+Sqrt[Il[[Xi]l]Ir[[Xi]r]] (Cos[[Phi][<<3>>]]
>   (Times[<<2>>]+Times[<<2>>])-(Times[<<2>>]+Times[<<2>>])
>   Sin[[Phi][<<3>>]]),<<1>>] in the first argument
>   {{ConditionalExpression[[Eta]r[[Xi]r]==Ir[[Xi]r]
>   (Times[<<2>>]+Times[<<2>>])+Il[[Xi]l]
>   (Im[<<1>>]+Times[<<2>>])+Sqrt[Times[<<2>>]]
>   (Times[<<2>>]+Times[<<3>>]),<<1>>],<<4>>,<<1>>},{[CapitalPhi][0,0,0]==[Pi],[Eta]r[0]==1.57389,[Eta]l[0]==1.57389}}.

I have 2 questions related to this problem:

- Can I somehow see what is <<1>>? As I undertand from here http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Skeleton.html <<1>> is a short form of some expression, when mathematica think that it is too long. I just want to see full text of this error.
- Can I tell to mathematica, that some of my unknown variables are real and more than 0. I am afraid, that I got this error message, because I have something like Sqrt[Ir*Il] in my system of PDE. and if mathematica think, that Ir and Il can be negative or complex, it will be very difficult to solve this system. I just want to tell mathematica try to find soliution only for positive Ir and Il. I tried to use Assuming like this

> Assuming[Ir is Reals && Ir > 0, NDSolve[...]]

but it does not help anyhow.

Update with full example. I have many Greek symbols, when I copied it, it became chnaged a little bit

```
ϵr:=Rationalize[0.001];
ϵl:=Rationalize[0.002];
KH:=Rationalize[0.12];
L := 1;
S := Sqrt[3]/4*L^2;
μ:=4*S/(WL*L);
ϕ0 :=Pi;



systemtosolve={
ηr[ξr]==Im[β[ξr]]*Ir[ξr]+Im[θl[ξl,ξr]]*Il[ξl] + (Im[σr[ξl, ξr]]*Cos[ϕ[t,ξl,ξr]]-Re[σr[ξl, ξr]]*Sin[ϕ[t,ξl,ξr]])*Sqrt[Ir[ξr]*Il[ξl]],

ηl[ξl]==Im[β[ξl]]*Il[ξl]+Im[θr[ξl,ξr]]*Ir[ξr] + (Im[σl[ξl, ξr]]*Cos[ϕ[t,ξl,ξr]]+Re[σl[ξl, ξr]]*Sin[ϕ[t,ξl,ξr]])*Sqrt[Ir[ξr]*Il[ξl]],

μ *D[Φ[t,ξl,ξr],t]==(ωj[ξr,ωab,ku]-ωj[ξl,ωab,ku])-c/L*KH*(
Re[Z[ξr]-Z[ξl]]
-Ir[ξr]*(Re[β[ξr]]-Re[θr[ξl,ξr]])
+Il[ξl]*(Re[β[ξl]]-Re[θl[ξl,ξr]])
-2*(Re[(σr[ξl, ξr]-σl[ξl, ξr])/2]*Cos[ϕ[t,ξl,ξr]]-Im[(σr[ξl, ξr]+σl[ξl, ξr])/2]*Sin[ϕ[t,ξl,ξr]])*Sqrt[Ir[ξ]*Il[ξ]]),

ηr[ξr]==Im[Z[ξr]]-ϵr/KH,

ηl[ξl]==Im[Z[ξl]]-ϵl/KH,

ϕ[t,ξl,ξr]==μ *Φ[t,ξl,ξr]+KH*Re[Z[ξr]-Z[ξl]]-ϕ0
};



ic = {
   Φ[0, 0, 0] == Pi,
   ηr[0] == Im[Z[0]] - ϵr/KH,
   ηl[0] == Im[Z[0]] - ϵr/KH
   };



vars = {ηr, ηl, Φ, Ir, Il};


syssolution = Assuming[ηr∈Reals&&ηr>0&&ηl∈Reals&&ηl>0Ir[ξr]∈Reals&&Ir[ξr]>0&&Il[ξl]∈Reals&&Il[ξl]>0&&Φ∈Reals&&Φ>0ξr∈Reals&& ξl∈Reals && ξr < 0.5 && ξr > -0.5&& ξl < 0.5 && ξl > -0.5, NDSolve[{systemtosolve,ic},vars,{t,0,10^-6},{ξr,-0.1,0.1},{ξl,-0.1,0.1}]];


NDSolve::deqn: "Equation or list of equations expected instead of ConditionalExpression[ηr[ξr]==Ir[ξr]\ (26/125\ (1+Times[<<2>>])+2\ Re[Times[<<2>>]])+Il[ξl]\ (Im[Times[<<2>>]+Times[<<4>>]+Times[<<2>>]]-13/125\ Re[Times[<<2>>]])+Sqrt[Il[ξl]\Ir[ξr]]\ (Cos[ϕ[<<3>>]]\ (Times[<<2>>]+Times[<<2>>])-(Times[<<2>>]+Times[<<2>>])\ Sin[ϕ[<<3>>]]),<<1>>] in the first argument {{ConditionalExpression[ηr[ξr]==Ir[ξr]\ (Times[<<2>>]+Times[<<2>>])+Il[ξl]\ (Im[<<1>>]+Times[<<2>>])+Sqrt[Times[<<2>>]]\ (Times[<<2>>]+Times[<<3>>]),<<1>>],<<4>>,<<1>>},{Φ[0,0,0]==π,ηr[0]==1.57389,ηl[0]==1.57389}}."
```

There are functions β, θl, σr, Z which are normal complex functions and they are working good, because before I have a graphs for all of them.

I made a screenshot for better understanding (Image is a small in preview. Please save it and open separately to have a good quality.)
[image]

Update2

I tried to minimize my system and I found the main reason, but I still do not know what I can do.

My code looks like this

```
KH := Rationalize[0.12]; 
L := 1; 
S := Sqrt[3]/4*L^2;
μ := 4*S/(WL*L); ϕ0 := Pi;

systemtosolve = {    D[Φ[t, ξl, ξr], t] == 1 +
     Cos[μ *Φ[t, ξl, ξr] + 
       KH*Re[Z[ξr] - Z[ξl]] - ϕ0]    };

ic = {    Φ[0, ξl, ξr] == Pi    };
vars = {Φ};

syssolution =    NDSolve[{systemtosolve, ic},     vars, {t, 0, 1}, {ξr, -0.1, 0.1}, {ξl, -0.1, 0.1}];

NDSolve::deqn: Equation or list of equations expected instead of ConditionalExpression[(Φ^(1,0,0))[t,ξl,ξr]==1-Cos[3/25 Plus[<<2>>]+1250000000/791 Power[<<2>>] Φ[<<3>>]],(((0.
-2. I) ξl∈Reals&&Re[(0. +2. I) ξl]<0.208)||Re[(0. -1. I) ξl]>-0.104)&&(((0. -2. I) ξr∈Reals&&Re[(0. +2. I) ξr]<0.208)||Re[(0. -1. I) ξr]>-0.104)] in the first argument {{ConditionalExpression[(Φ^(1,0,0))[t,ξl,ξr]==1-Cos[Plus[<<2>>]],((Times[<<2>>]∈Reals&&Re[<<1>>]<0.208)||Re[Times[<<2>>]]>-0.104)&&((Times[<<2>>]∈Reals&&Re[<<1>>]<0.208)||Re[Times[<<2>>]]>-0.104)]},{Φ[0,ξl,ξr]==π}}.
>>
```

The problem dissappeared if I remove function Z[]
This function is defined like this

```
Z[x_] := 2*I*Integrate[Exp[-y^2.0 + 2.0*I*y*x], {y, 0, Infinity}];
```

When I just calculate Z function or draw it's graph everything is fine, but NDSolve do not like this function somehow.

Can you help me to understand, what is wrong with Z function?

Comment: The expression you showed that was shortened is what `NDSolve` was given as an argument. It is complaining that the argument is NOT an equation or a list of equations. I think you have a syntax problem somewhere, not a numerical one. Can you show a minimal example of your code so we can reproduce the problem?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: In other words, following MarcoB, you can evaluate the first argument you gave to `NDSolve` to see what the message is complaining about.  Probably `ConditionalExpression` is not the construct you want.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I updated main question and added my code.

Comment: on use of assumptions: `DSolve` and `NDSolve` do not use assumptions themselves.  I can't find the reference on this now, but this came up before. Here is [dsolve-will-not-apply-assumption](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/46618/dsolve-will-not-apply-assumption-m-%E2%88%88-integers) question on assumptions with `DSolve`

Comment: If NDSolve does not use assumptions, how it works? It always thinks that all variables complex (like a+i*b)? or it always thinks that they are real? Because in my case I definitely have some complex functions in my system, but results should be real.

Comment: Looks like now a problem is clear. It happened because one of the functions has Integrate[] inside. Maybe somone know, why NDSolve cannot resolve the system, if one of the functions has Integrate? It is not an Integro-Differential equation. Just one known function has integral. It is something like Bessel function integral representation like mentioned here
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Bessel.27s_integrals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP still left out a definition (`WL`), but the problem is that `Integrate` generates a `ConditionalExpression`, on which `NDSolve` chokes.

```
2*I*Integrate[Exp[-y^2.0 + 2.0*I*y*x], {y, 0, Infinity}]
(*
  ConditionalExpression[
   2 I E^(-1. x^2) (0.886227 + (0. + 
         0.886227 I) Erfi[(1. + 0. I) x]), ((0. - 2. I) x ∈ 
       Reals && Re[(0. + 2. I) x] < 0) || Re[(0. - 1. I) x] > 0]
*)
```

One can specify the option `GenerateConditions -> False`, but perhaps the results may not be correct?  So let's try using assumptions, since `x` is real.  It's also risky to use approximate numbers when using `Integrate`, so let's change `2.0` to `2`.

```
2*I*Integrate[Exp[-y^2 + 2*I*y*x], {y, 0, Infinity}, Assumptions -> x ∈ Reals]
(*
  2 I (1/2 E^-x^2 Sqrt[π] + I DawsonF[x])
*)
```

I tested the OP's code (from "Update2") with the definition `WL = 1`, and a solution is produced without error.

Note: Given the problems with `Integrate` and complex-transcendental integrals, one should check this integral before proceeding.

Comment: Thank you very very much for your answer. WL = 1 is a good assumption, because it is just a constant (Wave Length in my case).

This is very great answer and I did not try it yet, but looks like it will help me a lot. I cannot vote up your answer because I have low reputation now, I just registered with stackexchange :(

Comment: Could you please also tell me, how you get this expression in comments (**) after integrate? I mean how can I get what integrate really do?

Comment: @Zlelik I get it by typing shift-return.  Do you mean when you execute the 2nd `Integrate`, you do not get `2 I (1/2 E^-x^2 Sqrt[π] + I DawsonF[x])`?  Perhaps, it depends on the version of *Mathematica*.  I'm using V10.1.  Completing the square inside the exponential, the integral is equivalent to `2*I*Exp[-x^2] Integrate[Exp[-(y - I x)^2], {y, 0, Infinity},  Assumptions -> x \[Element] Reals]` (with or without the `Assumptions`), which yields `I E^-x^2 Sqrt[\[Pi]] (1 + I Erfi[x])` and is equivalent.  Or is your question about something else?

Comment: I mean that I do not see 2 I (1/2 E^-x^2 Sqrt[π] + I DawsonF[x]) when I press shift+enter. Most probably I need to upgrade.

Comment: What do you think about using NIntegrate[] instead of Integrate[] with NDSolve? Because as I see NIntegrate is much faster in some cases. I really need only numerical calculations and most probably NIntegrate is completely fine for me. But when I tried to use it, I got another error message. I will try to put this error message a little bit later here. I do not have access to my Mathematica now.

Comment: @Zlelik `NIntegrate` can be used with `NDSolve` ([search for both](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=NIntegrate+NDSolve+is%3Aq)).  `NIntegrate` will end up being called hundreds or thousands of times depending on the DE.  You generally have to use it indirectly using `NumericQ`: `f[param_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[...]` and use `f` in `NDSolve`.  `Integrate` could be used only once, so one long computation vs. many short ones: hard to know which is faster.  `NIntegrate` introduces a presumably small error; for a sensitive DE, this could be a problem.

Comment: @Zlelik What happens when you try the alternate form, `2*I*Exp[-x^2] Integrate[Exp[-(y - I x)^2], {y, 0, Infinity}]`?  That's a pretty common Gaussian-type integral.  Works on V9.0.1, V10.

Comment: I will try to use your example with assumptions first, but I will be able to check it only after few hours. I will write the results here.

Comment: Now it works fine. Thanks a lot!!!

Could you please also explain me, what is the difference if I will use

`2*I*Integrate[Exp[-y^2 + 2*I*y*x], {y, 0, Infinity}, Assumptions -> x ∈ Reals]`

and this
`2*I*Exp[-x^2] Integrate[Exp[-(y - I x)^2], {y, 0, Infinity}]`
?

In other words, if first is working, what is the reason to use second approach?